# .NET Standard 2.0 reference not recognised in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, .net-standard, hololens

I am currently experimenting with the Hololens in combination with Unity. Part of the experiment is exchanging data with an existing .NET Framework application. This means that I have a number of libraries that are shared by both applications, which I have rewritten into .NET Standard 2.0 libraries so that they are compatible with both applications.

However, when I start referencing the .NET Standard 2.0 library in a Unity script, Unity gives the following error:

> error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral'.

I am having a lot of trouble figuring out what is causing this. When I check Edit -> Project Settings -> Player, I have Scripting Runtime Version set to .NET 4.x Equivalent; Scripting Backend to .NET; and Api Compatibility Level to .NET Standard 2.0. When I double click the error, it opens the Assembly-CSharp assembly in Visual Studio, where it shows v2.0 of *netstandard* among its references. When I lower the target of the libraries to .NET Standard 1.4, I no longer have the error, but unfortunately I have to use 2.0.

What do I need to set in order for Unity to recognise that v2.0 of *netstandard* is referenced?

I use Unity 2018.1.6f.
I have previously asked my question on [Unity Answers](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1523658/net-standard-20-reference-not-recognised.html), but it saw no responses there.

Thanks for reading.

**Edit:** Per request, here is the code in the Unity script:

```
using AugmentedReality.Device;

public class ServiceProvider
{
   #region Singleton
   private static ServiceProvider _instance;
   public static ServiceProvider Instance
   {
      get
      {
         if(_instance == null)
            _instance = new ServiceProvider();
         return _instance;
      }
   }
   #endregion

   public IOwnShipService OwnShipService;

   private ServiceProvider()
   {
      OwnShipService = new OwnShipService();
   }
}
```

And the OwnShipService in the .NET Standard 2.0 library:

```
namespace AugmentedReality.Device
{
   public interface IOwnShipService
   { }

   public class OwnShipService : IOwnShipService
   {
      public OwnShipService()
      { }
   }
}
```

This is enough to cause the error. I kept reducing the amount of code called to see what was causing it. Simply instantiating an empty class from the library is enough to trigger the error in Unity. I have included a [screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjZ22.png) as well.

Comment: Can you post the code that is generating that error?

Comment: @Draco18s Showing the code won't help much. All I do is instantiate a class from a .NET Standard 2.0 library, a simple 'Foo f = new Foo()'. It also compiles completely fine in Visual Studio, it's simply Unity that refuses to play nice.

Comment: Yes, but if I know *what* `Foo` you're calling `new` on, I can investigate to see what's going on with that object type.

Comment: @Draco18s Added the code.

Comment: Maybe (this thread)[https://forum.unity.com/threads/what-net-stack-for-uwp-hololens.522214/] in the Unity forum helps: `If you want to target .NET Standard 2.0 on UWP, use IL2CPP scripting backend`

Comment: [Fixed link](https://forum.unity.com/threads/what-net-stack-for-uwp-hololens.522214/). @Kay URLs have to be in (), so it's `[link text](url)`

Comment: @Kay The information in that thread concerns me. Regardless, setting it to IL2CPP seems to work, even if it brings a whole slew of other problems along. I guess there is no easy way to solve this then. Thanks.

Comment: Ever find a solution to this issue that is not using IL2CPP Scripting backend?

Comment: @AllenRufolo I am afraid not. Unity seems quite intent on killing off the .NET Scripting backend, so I simply have admitted defeat and started looking into IL2CPP. Unfortunately, the project was put on hold, so I haven't made much progress there either.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the IL2CPP scripting backend. This has a much larger .NET surface then the .NET scripting backend and the .NET scripting backend is being deprecated anyways.

Comment: The question was specifically meant for .NET Standard 2.0 support in the .NET Scripting Backend. This was before I knew it was being deprecated this year, so the question has lost its purpose. You are right that IL2CPP is the only way to go, although I haven't gotten the managed debugging to work yet.

Comment: Honestly, I haven't gotten the managed debugging working correctly either.  Only the c++ debugger.  Can't wait until that is fixed because debugging in c++ is a nightmare.